# System.InvalidOperationException: Failed with error code 0xe" at "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventProviderClone.Register"

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

While running my client code in Azure I am getting this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed with error code 0xe.
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventProviderClone.Register (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventSource..ctor (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.MessagingClientEtwProvider.get_Provider (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.<OnClosed>b__73_0 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.MessagingClientEtwProvider.TraceClient (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.OnClosed (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.Finalize (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

I am using the WIndowsAzure.ServiceBus v3.4.6 package.

My code to create the client is as such:

```
    private QueueClient QueueClient(string queueName)
    {
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusEndPoint);

        namespaceManager.Settings.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
            minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
            maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            maxRetryCount: 5);

        var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(namespaceManager.Address, namespaceManager.Settings.TokenProvider);

        messagingFactory.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
            minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            maxRetryCount: 5);

        var client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);

        client.RetryPolicy =
            new RetryExponential(
                minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
                maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                maxRetryCount: 5);

        return client;
    }
```

I'm at a loss about why this exception is happening.

Comment: `While running my client code in Azure`  Which service are you using? WebApp or  CloudService? The code works well in my local console  application.

Comment: It's a WebApp.  What's strange is we made a publish yesterday and Application Insights is not reporing the exception anymore so hopefully it was just a fluke.